# setup.bash refering to package and states file not found

Tags: ros, rocon, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am a Ubuntu 14.04 user using ROS Indigo. I am not sure what happened recently but when I do [In catkin workspace] source devel/setup.bash I get the following error message

```
bash: /home/dinu94/catkin_ws/src/rocon/src/rocon_app_platform/rocon_app_utilities/shells/env.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/dinu94/catkin_ws/src/rocon/src/rocon_tools/rocon_launch/shells/env.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/dinu94/catkin_ws/src/rocon/src/rocon_multimaster/rocon_test/shells/env.bash: No such file or directory
bash: /home/dinu94/catkin_ws/src/rocon/src/rocon_tools/rocon_python_comms/completion/rospairbash: No such file or directory
```

I had installed rocon months before and deleted in quite recently. I don't know how this polluted setup.bash . I can't understand the code and hence unable to fix it. Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222256/setup.bash-refering-to-package-and-states-file-not-found/) by [creative_cimmons](https://answers.ros.org/users/22559/creative_cimmons/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I had installed rocon months before and deleted in quite recently.

Assuming you no longer need the mentioned package, you can delete both `build` and `devel` directories in your catkin workspace and build again; some settings that you generated "months before" when you still needed the package still try to refer to them.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2015-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2